# How to correct the route that results from running a Controller Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Below is a very simple MVC triplet, implemented to try the things out.

It seems to work except the URL I get after changing a Status code to say 500 and hitting Submit button is `Error/StatusCode`, not `Error/StatusCode/500`. How can I change it?

I appreciate it is a simple question, but I could not find correct key words to google out the answer.

**Model**

```
public class ErrorModel
{
    [DisplayName("Status Code")]
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }

    public ErrorModel(string statusCode)
    {
        HttpStatusCode code;
        if (! Enum.TryParse(statusCode, out code))
        {
            code = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }
        StatusCode = ((int)code).ToString();
    }

    public ErrorModel(HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        StatusCode = ((int)statusCode).ToString();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@using WebApplication1.Models
@model WebApplication1.Models.ExcelModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("StatusCode", "Error", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StatusCode)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StatusCode, null, "id")
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    static readonly List<HttpStatusCode> ErrorCodes = new List<HttpStatusCode>(){
        HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, HttpStatusCode.NotFound, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError};

    public ActionResult StatusCode(string id)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "";
        if ((id == null) || (ErrorController.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, id)))
        {
            return View("StatusCode", new ErrorModel(HttpStatusCode.OK));
        }
        foreach (HttpStatusCode errorCode in ErrorCodes)
        {
            if (ErrorController.AreEqual(errorCode, id))
            {
                return View("HttpError", new ErrorModel(errorCode));
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Message = "Exception " + id
            + @" is not supported, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx for further details";
        return View("HttpError", new ErrorModel(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError));
    }

    static private bool AreEqual(HttpStatusCode httpCode, string statusCode)
    {
        return (statusCode == ((int)httpCode).ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use jquery ajax to send data as a route value to the server.

Comment: You are posting when you submit -- that will not include the code in the URL, only the base route.

Comment: @AbbasAmiri, could you add an answer with a snippet in it?

Comment: @dbugger: by adding an {id = Model.StatusCode} I am able to add an id value to URL, but it is always the initial value (200) regardless of the value I am submitting. I was hoping there is a way to fetch correct value...

Answer (score 1):

You are using `POST` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) to submit the form. That will not include the form element values in the url, but in the request body.

If you want your form field values to be part of the URL, Change the form method to `GET`. When using `GET`,if a form is posted, the data sent to the server is appended to the URL as query string values.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("StatusCode", "Error", FormMethod.Get))
{   
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StatusCode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StatusCode, null, "id")
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />      
}
```

Now when user submits the form, browser will issue a GET request to the `Error/StatusCode` url with the form data appended to the url.

```
/Home/StatusCode?id=500
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically changing the action's url could be a solution and the code below shows a simplest way to do that.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(){
            this.action = this.action  + '/' + $('#StatusCode').val();
        })
    });
</script>
```